# C# Ms-access Getting details from database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, authentication, oledb

I've created a login form using SQL, OLEDB Provider, which prompts the user for a name and password and if both match the username and password record in the Microsoft Access database then it directs them to a different form, however I don't know how to go about accessing all their information, e.g. Name, Surname and Age to display it as this obviously needs to be linked to who they have logged in as.

Can I link this to the name they've entered into the login text box if it's successful or is there a better way to load their details depending on who has logged in?

Comment: is this remotely related to the included `mysql` tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create 2 classes.One static class called Login that handles details of user logged in,rights assigned etc.Username and password will be passed to a method in this class, decrypted here,checked if correct and returns instance of User class:

```
public static class Login{
 public static User LoggedUser {get; private set;}
 public static bool Authenticate(string userName, string password){
   //(a)Logic to fetch data based on username and pwd. mostly i use  Entityframework
   var user=context.Users.Find(x=>x.Name=userName && x.Pwd=MethodHelper.Decrypt(password));
   LoggedUser=user
   return LoggedUser != null;
 }
}
```

To use it:
(1) Login form.
    if(Login.Authenticate(txtUserName.Text,txtPassword.Text){
    //direct to another form if true. Just by doing this it also sets the  loggedUser property of this class.
    }else{ //access denied logic}

(2)Other scenarios like display name on mainform status bar.

```
statusBarLabelUserName.Text=Login.LoggedUser.Name;
statusBarLabelSurname.Text=Login.LoggedUser.surname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure of your Access db, and the tables involved, probably the personal details will be associated with some sort of unique user ID.

That's what you should be using to get their data. When login is successful, you should use the userID to get the details you need.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that, all tables include the memberID as the foreign key. Do you have an idea on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Well, you don't include much in the way of detail in your question. If you're running authentication, though, the queries should be pretty easy. When the login was successful, you'd do something like set memberID in a session variable, and as the user browsed the site, the memberID would be used to select the data for that user.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Sorry for my lack of detail, I couldn't think of a better way of describing it :).

Comment: Does that help answer your question, though?

Comment: Yeah this and the answer Nduerere provided gives me a detailed idea on how to go about this, thanks :)